# Disable app Today Extension in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, today-extension

I would like to **disable/enable a widget (Today Extension)** for my OS X app based on an in-app purchase. Here's what I know so far:

- For the container app, it's easy to check the purchase, cause I have the app receipt which I validate.
- Today Extensions don't have a receipt file, so I can't check that.
- I don't really want to store it in Core Data or User Defaults, cause they are pretty easy to crack.
- The best solution would be to dynamically add & remove the widget for the Notification Center, but that's probably hard.

What would you suggest? If you have a solution for iOS, that might help as well.

Comment: It is a feature of OS X you can't block features from the platform for an in app purchase. See the review guidelines for more details.